# Warning on Pantheon Localdev logs

Tags: pantheon

Hi I'm spinning out [Pantheon's Localdev](https://pantheon.io/pantheon-localdev-power-users-pre-releasehttps://pantheon.io/pantheon-localdev-power-users-pre-release) for testing and I'm getting this warning message on the logs

> You have a lot of keys!

Any ideas what is causing this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to [lando](https://docs.lando.dev/config/pantheon.html). This thread on Github suggests:

1. To disable the warning you can run `lando config` you will see a `maxKeyWarning` setting. This value can be overridden in a [lando global](https://docs.lando.dev/config/global.html#config-yml) config file, i.e. set the value that matches your number of used keys..
2. As documented in the [SSH keys config page](https://docs.lando.dev/config/ssh.html#customizing), the keys key is meant to be used in combination with a [user-space Lando override file](https://docs.lando.dev/config/lando.html#override-file). This file is .gitignored and is meant to provide user-specific overrides, eg you would not put ALL the keys of ALL the users here, just yours.

Comment: Sorry I've been experimenting some issues with Docker for Mac and I've not being able to test this. Seems good, thanks.

Comment: @d70rr3s No worries, sorry to hear. It seems to be the common answer to this question. Feel free to check back later or vote anytime.